# Problems regarding UICreation in XAML Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I have created XAML ,with grid structure ,with 3 or 4 rows ,each row containing two columns,If i want to set the color for the each row and border line around each row and column ,how can i achieve  it.

I am new to this Ui creation in XAML especially,Anyidea regarding how to achieve this will be useful`

```
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="Account Number :"   Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="accNO" Text="" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10"/>

                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Currency  :" Grid.Row="1" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="accCurr" Text="" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Acount Balance  :" Grid.Row="2" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="accOBal" Text="" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="Available Balance :" Grid.Row="3" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="avBal" Text="" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10"/>

                </Grid>`
```

I have updated codes for getting table as my requirements

```
  <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="1,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="LightGray" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>                           
                        </Border.Background>
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black"  Text="Account Number :"   Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  />
                    </Border>

                    <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Black" x:Name="accNO" Text="" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10"/>
                    </Border>
```

Thanks For help.It was done for the first row of grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want border around each row and column, then set the Border element inside every row and column

```
<Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
    <TextBlock Text="This is some text." />
</Border>
```

Comment: Is there any property to set the background color for every row  and every column?

Comment: For the whole row and for the whole column, or for every row/column combination?

Comment: Hi,I am trying to get some background color for whole rows 0 and row2 and row 1 and 3 the other background color.

Comment: You can set the background for the whole Grid only. If you don't want to do that, then you need to add some UI elements that take up the whole rows (for example: <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Background="Black" /> )

Comment: hi,I was able to achievve as i was expecting,Thanks